# How to add new index and value from another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help with my problem. My problem is I have 2 arrays the first one is the main array. The second is the array for my new data.

Let's say I have these arrays.

This is the main array:

```
Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Apple',
            'age' => 12
         )

    1 => Array
        (
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => May,
            'age' => 13
         )
)
```

This is the second array:

```
Array
(
    1 => Array
        (
            'gender' => 'Male'
        )

    2 => Array
        (
            'gender' => 'Female'
        )

)
```

And I have this loop in PHP

```
foreach($main_array as &$main){

   //this is the loop inside the first array
   // how can I add the second array with it?

}
```

This is the sample output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Apple
        [age] => 12
        [gender] => Female
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => May
        [age] => 13
        [gender] => Female
     )
```

How can I do that? Any suggestions? That's all thanks.

Comment: What you mean by "add the second array with it"?

Comment: Is the second array keys are id of the first array ?

Comment: I mean I just want to add the gender in my first array

Comment: All you need is standard function array_merge_recursive() (see  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php )

Comment: @Ilya `array_merge_recursive` doesn't merge values for numeric keys (as in given arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your example code, it wont run otherwise.

```
<?php

// Test data:
$main_array = Array(
  0 => Array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Apple',
    'age' => 12
  ),
  1 => Array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'May',
    'age' => 13
  )
);
$lookup = Array(
  1 => Array(
    'gender' => 'Male'
  ),
  2 => Array(
    'gender' => 'Female'
  )
);

// Your answer:
foreach ($main_array as &$main) {
  if (array_key_exists($main['id'],$lookup)) {
    $main['gender'] = $lookup[$main['id']]['gender'];  // <-- sets gender value
  }
}

// Output it to browser:
echo '<pre>$main_array = '.print_r($main_array,true).'</pre>';
```

The `array_key_exists()` check is there to avoid errors such as `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 123` when the `$lookup` data is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($main_array); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($second_array); $j++){
        if($main_array[$i]['id'] == $j){
            $main_array[$i]['gender'] = $second_array[$j]['gender']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## If you want to merge all of the data from both arrays:

### PHP tools:

The exact behaviors of these functions needs to be studied and tested before usage, to make sure it fits your intent.

```
//  array merge recursive doesn't merge numeric keys
$main_array = array_merge_recursive($main_array, $secondary_array);

//  array replace recursive has a downside of replacing stuff
$main_array = array_replace_recursive($main_array, $secondary_array);
```

### Rolling your own:

```
foreach($main_array as $i => &$main){
    if(isset($secondary_array[$i])) {
        foreach($secondary_array[$i] AS $key => $value) {
            $main[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Both of the above solutions only apply if the array-indexes of `$main_array` and `$secondary_array` match.

In your example your arrays don't match:
- `$secondary_array[0]` doesn't exist so `$main_array[0]` will not be populated with a `'gender'` value;
- `$main_array[2]` doesn't exist so `$main_array[2]` will be created and it will only have a `'gender'` value same as `$secondary_array[2]['gender']`

---

## If you want to only merge some bits and pieces of the arrays:

### Rolling your own:

```
foreach($main_array as $i => &$main) {
    if(isset($secondary_array[$i])) and isset($secondary_array[$i]['gender'])) {
        $main['gender'] = $secondary_array[$i]['gender'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok sir I will try it but what if I have another element in the second array? How can I select only the gender?

Comment: Please update the question with these specifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($main_array as &$main){//this is the loop inside the first array
    foreach($second_array as &$second){ //this is the loop inside the second array

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($arr1 as $k => $arr1Item) {
   $arr1[$k]['gender'] = $arr2[$k]['gender'];
}
```